# Use of Countifs to check values from two different columns to match a criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I have a data with 3 tabs. Tab 1 has information to be analyzed in tab 3. So in tab 1 I have column J and K which have responses of either "yes" or "No" in one row. So if for example row 5 column J shows "Yes" while K shows No/ J"No" and K"Yes"/both J and K shows No, I term that as an error. If both J and K are Yes then I need not to count that. Which formular can I use.

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Answer (score 0):

You have specifically referenced `COUNTIFS()` for the answer to your question. Please consider that there are likely to be several other alternatives (including `filter` and `query`) that will also produce the same result.

**Establishing criteria**

In your analysis, you defined an error as any of the following:

- J = "Yes" and K = "No"
- J = "No" and K = "Yes"
- J and K shows "No"

As shown below, "J and K shows No" is redundant because it is covered under the criterion of "J = "No".

**Formula**

`=COUNTIFS(J4:J23,"<>Yes")+COUNTIFS(J4:J23,"Yes",K4:K23,"No")`

---

[image: Sample data]

---

[image: Formulae]

---